# Why is my Fedora 14 install failing?

Tags: fedora, install

While trying to install Amahi and Fedora 14 from 5 discs, I get this error:
[image]

It says:

> A fatal error occurred when installing the module-init-tools package.  This could indicate errors when reading installation media.  Installation cannot continue.

When prompted, I opted to install the Fedora repository, the Fedora Updates repo, and added an Amahi repo.  I didn't select the Fedora Test Updates repo.

The checksums of the downloaded files are correct, and the media test approved all 5 of my CDs.  What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried installing without using any on-line repositories, just the CDs? Maybe its failing to download a package for some reason. Install from just the local media, then use yum to update afterwards.

Comment: The repositories were it.  I selected only the install repo and the Amahi repo and it worked.  Still curious as to why though....

Comment: And yes, I said in my question: `the media test approved all 5 of my CDs`